# How to remove/trim .xml tags using javascript code

Tags: javascript, xml, string, tags, trim

//  Need to separately get the text between tags through javascript. For example, given an xml file with: Burger I would need to extract just the Burger part and display it.

// I tried using: document.getElementById(" ").innerXML =  ; but it didn't work with my IDE (repl.it).

```
// this is my code so far I need to get the name, description, and prices out of their tags and display them in separate parallel arrays.

// References: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript


main();

function main() {
  var filename = "final.xml";

  var names = [];
  console.log(names);

  var descriptions = [];
  console.log(descriptions);

  var prices = [];
  console.log(prices);

  var fs = require('fs');
  var contents = fs.readFileSync("final.xml", 'utf8');

  lines = contents.split('\n');

  for (var index = 0; index < lines.length; index++)  {


  var x = lines[index].match(/<name>(.*?)<\/name>/g);
  var y = lines[index].match(/<description>(.*?)<\/description>/g);
  var z = lines[index].match(/<price>(.*?)<\/price>/g);

  if (isNaN(x)) {

          names.push(x[0]);
  }

  if (isNaN(y)) {

          descriptions.push(y[0]);
  }

  if (isNaN(z)) {

          prices.push(z[0]);
        }
  }

console.log(names);
console.log(descriptions);
console.log(prices);

}
```

Comment: [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [Element.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) will ignore tags.